# why my Fullcalendar saved events goes to the day before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, fullcalendar

**Hi there**,
I needed a calendar for my website so i discovered fullcalendar.js which is awesome!

I created a calendar where is it possible to set events and to save the events by a cookie.
Actually it works but when i set an event, save it on the FIRST time and reaload my calendar => The event goes to the day before!!??

I don't understand why!
Maybe someone can help me?

My code is there :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='../jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='../jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {


                /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        var savedEvents = $.cookie("DSCalendar");
        if(savedEvents)
        {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;

                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);                
                },
                events: JSON.parse(savedEvents)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    alert(copiedEventObject.start);
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);


                }
            });
        }


        $("#save").click(function(){
            var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
            var eventsForCookie = [];

            $.each(eventsFromCalendar, function(index,value) {
                var event = new Object();
                event.id = value.id;
                event.start = value.start;
                alert('event = '+event.start);
                event.end = value.end;
                event.title = value.title;
                eventsForCookie.push(event);
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(eventsForCookie));
            $.cookie("DSCalendar", JSON.stringify(eventsForCookie), {expires: 1});

            var savedEvents = $.cookie("DSCalendar");

            console.log(JSON.parse(savedEvents));

        });

});

</script>
<style>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #wrap {
        width: 1100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

    #external-events {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: left;
        }

    #external-events h4 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 1em;
        }

    .external-event { /* try to mimick the look of a real event */
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 2px 4px;
        background: #3366CC;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: .85em;
        cursor: pointer;
        }

    #external-events p {
        margin: 1.5em 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #666;
        }

    #external-events p input {
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        }

    #calendar {
        float: right;
        width: 900px;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='wrap'>

<div id='external-events'>
<h4>Draggable Events</h4>
<div class='external-event'>Free on the Morning</div>
<div class='external-event'>Free on the After-noon</div>
<div class='external-event'>Free on the night</div>
<div class='external-event'>Free all the day</div>
<p>
<input type='button' id='save' /> <label for='save'>save</label>
</p>
</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>

<div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution**

The date hours are set to 00:00 so tried to change the date by doing `date.setHours(15);` and now that works.

Comment: I got an exception in javascript : setHours is undefined method. Do you have the same issue?